# Multi-term issue with line wrapping for shell but not applications

Tags: spacemacs, shell, term, multi-term

I use multi-term within spacemacs for most of my command-line operations.
It works well except some annoying behavior in the shell prompt (zsh but similar for bash) on commands which go over the screen width.

I tried many things without success to fix it but I discovered that if I run the same shell within neovim within multi-term the prompt has no problem.
Of course that is not ideal as I cannot scroll up but it may help to isolate the issue.

See below the behavior (I type "l" repeatedly then backspace):

[image: Screencast]

Spacemacs (0.200.13@26.1, Ubuntu 16.04, same issue with 25.3) configuration related to the terminal

```
(setq multi-term-switch-after-close nil)
(setq term-suppress-hard-newline t)
(setq term-char-mode-point-at-process-mark nil)
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook '(lambda () (toggle-truncate-lines 1)))
```

The issue appears regardless of the value of toggle-truncate-lines.

Any idea of what could cause this behavior?

EDIT:
I debugged with `(setq term-log-buffer t)` and the syntax highlighting in zsh makes things even more complex.
Disabling it, the cursor simply returns to the beginning of the line instead of one line below:

[image]

It seems that when the line reaches the screen width, the shell sends `^M^[[K`, a carriage return and a line kill, so `emacs` does as expected.
Not sure why the shell does not return a line feed too.

With `bash --norc`, the shell sends only `^M` at the end of the line so `emacs` keeps overwriting the same line without erasing it like for `zsh`.

EDIT2:
Learning more about terminals, the shell behavior seems to be [standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31360700).
The issue is then that `emacs` doesn't properly handle the <kbd>SP</kbd><kbd>CR</kbd> sequence in this case.

EDIT3:
Reported as a bug.

Comment: Does it happen with `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: Yes exactly the same behavior.

Comment: I was about to point the finger at `term-suppress-hard-newline`, but that is set to `nil` by default, so it can't be that.